# React JS Access Data JSON via props

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

My data is currently in a JSON format and is successfully being populated to props called `foxFooterData`.

When I console.log foxFooterData.data you see the following: [image]

I'm trying to access the foxFooterCopyright text you see within the object.

I thought doing `{this.props.foxFooterData.data.foxFooterCopyright}` would work but no luck.

Here is also a true representation of the data as it's coming through:

[image]

EDIT - Updating with extra code:

Reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state={
    data: {},
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null,
}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_FOXFOOTER_DATA": {
            return {...state, fetching: true}
        }
        case "FETCH_FOXFOOTER_DATA_COMPLETE": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: false,
                fetched: true,
                data: action.payload
            }
        }
        case "FETCH_FOXFOOTER_DATA_FAILED": {
            return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
        }
    }

    return state

}
```

Action:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchFoxFooterData() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8888/public/api/globals/foxFooterLegal.json')
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_FOXFOOTER_DATA_COMPLETE", payload: response.data})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: "FETCH_FOXFOOTER_DATA_FAILED", payload: err})
        })
    }
}
```

Container Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

//Actions
import {fetchAdProductsData} from '../../actions/adProductsActions';
import {fetchListAdProductData} from '../../actions/listAdProductsActions';
import {fetchFoxFooterData} from '../../actions/foxFooterActions';

//Components
import Header from '../../components/Header';
import HeroModule from '../../components/HeroModule';
import ProductCategoryLeft from '../../components/ProductCategoryLeft';
import ProductCategoryRight from '../../components/ProductCategoryRight';
import ProductCategoryNavigation from '../../components/ProductCategoryNavigation';
import HeroDetail from '../../components/HeroDetail';
import ShowcaseModule from '../../components/ShowcaseModule';
import NewsModule from '../../components/NewsModule';
import ContactModule from '../../components/ContactModule';
import Footer from '../../components/Footer';

@connect((store) => {
    return {
        listAdProductsData: store.ListAdProductsData.data,
        adProductsData: store.AdProductsData.data,
        foxFooterData: store.FoxFooterData.data
    }
})

class AdProducts extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        //Fetch Ad Products Data
        //this.props.dispatch(fetchAdProductsData())


        //Fetch List Ad Products Data
        this.props.dispatch(fetchListAdProductData())

        //Fetch Fox Footer Data
        this.props.dispatch(fetchFoxFooterData())

    }

    render() {
        console.log("DATA", this.props.foxFooterData.data.data[0].foxFooterCopyright);
        return (
            <div className="ad-products-wrap container no-padding col-xs-12">
                <Header />
                <HeroModule />
                <HeroDetail />
                <ProductCategoryLeft />
                <ProductCategoryNavigation />
                <ProductCategoryRight />
                <ShowcaseModule />
                <NewsModule />
                <ContactModule />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AdProducts
```

Comment: Cue the fastest gun in the west... and the 1000 edits.

Comment: Still no luck with this - any answers are welcome!

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(store.FoxFooterData)` in the connect function? What is the output of `props.foxFooterData`. Console.log this in render.

Comment: @MartinDawson Nothing within the connect function - I didn't think you could log within there. The other this.props.foxFooterData within the render returns the data / object

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the full path as well it being case-sensitive.

`this.props.FoxFooterData.data.data[0].foxFooterCopyright`

Comment: @filth can you show more code? Specifically where you are trying to access the data.

Comment: Trying to access it within my container - I will add my actions, reducer and container code to the original post

Comment: Can you try `this.props.FoxFooterData.data[0].foxFooterCopyright`

Comment: Tried - still same issue... I have tried a lot of these, no clue why hence the post!

Comment: @filth you do have the capital `F` in `FoxFooterData` correct?

Comment: Yes I'm copying as you're writing in the comments.

Comment: Maybe @LeeBenson can be of more help to you.

Comment: Haha I hope anyone can help at this stage... thank you for your help so far dude

Answer (score 0):

Based on your graphic, the full object path to the `foxFooterCopyright` key is:

```
this.props.FoxFooterData.data.data[0].foxFooterCopyright
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined - see comments below on other answer

Comment: Try both `this.props.foxFooterData[0].foxFooterCopyright` and `this.props.foxFooterData.data[0].foxFooterCopyright`

Comment: ok the first one returned foxFooterCopyright undefined and the second one was Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Do me a favour. `console.log(this.props.foxFooterData)` and paste _exactly_ what it returns

Comment: that passes and returns an empty object

Comment: Move the console.log into the `FETCH_FOXFOOTER_DATA_COMPLETE` reducer switch, so we can see the data before it's passed to React

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157593/discussion-between-filth-and-lee-benson).

Answer (score 0):

add this life cycle hook to your code, will be triggered as soon as your props are injected to your component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
 if(newProps.foxFooterData && newProps.foxFooterData.data && 
   newProps.foxFooterData.data.length){

   console.log("DATA", this.props.foxFooterData.data[0].foxFooterCopyright);

 }

}
```

Comment: add these checks

Comment: I did and still nothing :-(

Comment: it shuould work. add a breakpoint inside the componentWillReceiveProps hook